# My handler exception in spring boot no capture exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, exception, java-11

I have my handler exception, my controller and I apply the javax Validation for the body request for my controller. But when one attribute of my body request not cumplimented the validation configuration my handler no capture my MethodArgumentNotValidException. I have not dublicated @ControllerAdvice in my proyect. Maybe Spring don't load my component correctly?

My controller:

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/consents")
public class ConsentsController {
    
    @PostMapping(path="/altaConsentimientos")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<OutAltaConsentimientos>> postAltaConsentimiento(@Valid @RequestBody InAltaConsentimientos inDto) throws Exception{
        System.out.print("Hola esto es una prueba");
    //  throw new Exception();
        return null;
    }

}
```

My InAltaConsentimientos:

```
 @Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class InAltaConsentimientos implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NotBlank(message ="usuario_id is mandatory")
    @Email(message ="usuario_id is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("usuario_id")
    private String id;
    @NotBlank(message ="usuario_nombre is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("usuario_nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @NotBlank(message ="usuario_apellidos is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("usuario_apellidos")
    private String apellidos;
    @NotBlank(message ="usuario_email is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("usuario_email")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank(message ="consentimiento_fecha is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("consentimiento_fecha")
    private String fechaDelConsentimiento;
    @NotBlank(message ="consentimiento_tipo is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("consentimiento_tipo")
    private String tipoConsentimiento;
    @NotBlank(message ="consentimiento_valor is mandatory")
    @JsonProperty("consentimiento_valor")
    private String valorConsentimiento;
}
```

My handler exception:

```
    @ControllerAdvice
public class HandleValidationExceptions {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandleValidationExceptions.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class,Exception.class})
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorMessage handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
//          String message=exception.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().stream()
//          .map(fieldError -> fieldError.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
//  
    //  logger.error(message, exception);
        return new ErrorMessage(exception, "Malformed parameter: ");
        //ResponseEntity<?> response = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
        
        //return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Campos malformateados");
    }
}
```

My Boot app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"es.","es.wsconsents","es.wsconsents.exceptions"})
//@ComponentScan({"es.servihabitat.consentimientos.api"})
public class ConsentsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsentsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*I put my handler exception package in @ScanPackage in Boot class

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned that you have added your exception class's package in your app configuration , i beleive the issue is that you have not added `HandleValidationExceptions` or its package to the configuration.
we have no way of knowing that without you attaching the full classes and the app config.

Comment: Ok I edit my question